# Rails ActiveMerchant - Paypal Express Checkout Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, activemerchant

I am getting this error when I call this code.

```
response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(order.price_in_cents,
  :ip                => request.remote_ip,
  :return_url        => url_for(:action => :create, :only_path => false),
  :cancel_return_url => root_path
)

redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
```

Error:

```
This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.
```

To show I setup EXPRESS_GATEWAY correctly. code development.rb file.

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
  paypal_options = {
    :login => '*****************************',
    :password => '*************',
    :signature => '*******************************************************'
  }
  ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)
end
```

Gem file

```
gem 'activemerchant', :require => 'active_merchant'
```

So the login, password, and sig. were created in the sandbox are of paypal. So they should be working.

What should I try to get this error fixed. Or is this Paypal's side? Is there something wrong in the ActiveMerchant gem?

**UPDATE 1**

After inspecting the response var, this is what I get.

```
#<ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressResponse:0x00000102402790 @params={"timestamp"=>"2012-06-29T01:30:18Z", "ack"=>"Failure", "correlation_id"=>"d1cb5dbb30425", "version"=>"72", "build"=>"3067390", "message"=>"CancelURL is invalid.", "error_codes"=>"10472", "Timestamp"=>"2012-06-29T01:30:18Z", "Ack"=>"Failure", "CorrelationID"=>"d1cb5dbb30425", "Errors"=>{"ShortMessage"=>"Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.", "LongMessage"=>"CancelURL is invalid.", "ErrorCode"=>"10472", "SeverityCode"=>"Error"}, "Version"=>"72", "Build"=>"3067390"}, @message="CancelURL is invalid.", @success=false, @test=true, @authorization=nil, @fraud_review=false, @avs_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil}, @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil}>
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

**UDPATE 2**

Turns out after looking at that message above, it was the cancelURL that was invalid, so I fixed that and presto!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error is shown when you are not properly logged into the sandbox account on paypal's site.

1. Login to http://sandbox.paypal.com/
2. Open your site and checkout
3. When sent to paypal, login as one of your buyer test accounts

Comment: I didn't create a buyer account. Let me test that and see if that fixes it.